# Creating a new environment in conda with python 3.5 on Mac

Tags: python, installation, conda, environment

I am trying to create a new environment named cv_env having python 3.5 , with this line -

> conda create --name cv_env python=3.5

Although it gives an error,

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
> python=3.5

Comment: i guess the command you have given that it is for windows and you want to create in mac

Comment: I guess the command is same for both windows and mac. Else, can you please share what command should i use in mac?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and installed anaconda. This time the command worked.